# What is the correct workflow status in JIRA to do the retest?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to have my company transition to JIRA from email for bug tracking purposes, and I can't figure out one thing: why JIRA (and BitBucket's Issues, which is sort of a limited version of JIRA) don't have a "Ready for retest" status.

I imagine the flow works like this:

- Bug is reported
- Bug is handled by developer
- Developer marks bug as ready for retest
- Tester tests, marks "Resolved" or "Closed" if all is OK, otherwise back to "Open".

Apparently I misunderstand something or other people don't work in the same way. What's the correct workflow status for the testers to retest the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, or your jira administrator, can create your own status in Jira. Look in Jira adminstration/ issues/ issue attributes and there you can add a status.

Then you still need to add that status to your project workflow, but that is another story.

Here is a link to help with all of it: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/define-new-status-or-steps-in-jira-workflow-718835875.html

Answer (score 2):

Some organizations use the "Resolved" state to mean what you do by "ready for retest", then move the bug to "Closed" when the retest is successful. This would let you use the default workflow without adding states.